Can not Set Property value in Type Conversion Issue When Setting Property Values in Patch Operation
I'm trying to create a batch update endpoint in my ASP.NET Core application. The method should take a collection of PatchObject items and apply the changes to the respective entities. However, I'm encountering a type conversion problem when setting the values to the properties.
Here is my code:
[HttpPost("PatchBatch")]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> PatchBatch([FromBody] ICollection<PatchObject> patchRequests)
{
    if (patchRequests == null || !patchRequests.Any())
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Cannot complete operation, collection parameter is null or empty");
    }

    var errors = new List<string>();

    foreach (var patchRequest in patchRequests)
    {
        try
        {
            var currentEntity = await _service.GetByIdAsync(patchRequest.Id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
            
            if (currentEntity == null)
            {
                errors.Add($"Entity with id {patchRequest.Id} not found.");
                continue;
            }

            var patch = new Delta<T>();
            foreach (var change in patchRequest.Changes)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!patch.TrySetPropertyValue(change.Key, change.Value))
                    {
                        errors.Add($"The value {change.Value} cannot be set to property {change.Key}");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {
                    errors.Add($"Property {change.Key} does not exist on the entity.");
                    continue;
                }
            }

            patch.Patch(currentEntity);
            await _service.UpdateAsync(currentEntity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errors.add($"An error occurred while updating the entity with id: {patchRequest.Id}. Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    if (errors.Any())
    {
        return BadRequest(string.Join("\n", errors));
    }

    return Ok("Batch update successful.");
}

public class PatchObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Changes { get; set; }
}


The issue arises when patch.TrySetPropertyValue(change.Key, change.Value) attempts to set the property value. It fails due to type conversion problems, resulting in errors being added to the error list. Here are the types of errors I'm encountering:
The value cannot be set to the property
**Questions:
How can I handle type conversion properly in this scenario?
What is the best way to ensure that the properties exist on the entity and are correctly typed?
Are there more efficient methods for performing batch updates that avoid these issues?**
i tried converting like this, but i am facing conversion errors.
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(change.Key.ToString());
        if (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            errors.Add($"Property {change.Key} does not exist on T.");
            continue;
        }

        Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        object convertedValue = ConvertToType(change.Value, propertyType);

        if (!patch.TrySetPropertyValue(change.Key, convertedValue))
        {
            errors.Add($"The value {change.Value} cannot be converted to {propertyType}");
            continue;
        }


I test it in my local and make it works in my side.
If you are faing other convet type issues(specific types), you can debug it in ConvertToType method. And add it.

PatchHelper.cs
using System.Reflection;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class PatchHelper
    {
        public static void ApplyPatch<T>(T entity, Dictionary<string, object> changes) where T : class
        {
            foreach (var change in changes)
            {
                var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(change.Key, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (property != null && property.CanWrite)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var convertedValue = ConvertToType(change.Value, property.PropertyType);
                        property.SetValue(entity, convertedValue);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot convert value '{change.Value}' to type {property.PropertyType} for property {property.Name}", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static object ConvertToType(object value, Type targetType)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                if (targetType.IsValueType)
                {
                    return Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);
                }
                return null;
            }

            if (targetType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
            {
                return value;
            }

            try
            {
                if (targetType.IsEnum)
                {
                    return Enum.Parse(targetType, value.ToString());
                }

                if (targetType == typeof(Guid))
                {
                    return Guid.Parse(value.ToString());
                }

                if (targetType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    return DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
                }

                if (targetType == typeof(System.Int32))
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString());
                }

                if (targetType == typeof(double))
                {
                    return Convert.ToDouble(value);
                }

                if (targetType == typeof(decimal))
                {
                    return Convert.ToDecimal(value);
                }

                if (targetType == typeof(System.String))
                {
                    return Convert.ToString(value);
                }

                return Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot convert value '{value}' to type {targetType}", ex);
            }
        }
    }

}

ITestEntityService.cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using WebApplication1.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public interface ITestEntityService
    {
        Task<TestEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id);
        Task UpdateAsync(TestEntity entity);
        Task<IDbContextTransaction> BeginTransactionAsync();
    }
}

TestEntityService.cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using WebApplication1.Areas.Identity.Data;
using WebApplication1.Data;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class TestEntityService: ITestEntityService
    {
        private readonly DBContext _context;

        public TestEntityService(DBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<TestEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _context.TestEntities.FindAsync(id);
        }

        public async Task UpdateAsync(TestEntity entity)
        {
            _context.TestEntities.Update(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IDbContextTransaction> BeginTransactionAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
        }
    }
}

TestController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Data;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ITestEntityService _service;

        public TestController(ITestEntityService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }


        [HttpPost("PatchBatch")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PatchBatch([FromBody] ICollection<PatchObject> patchRequests)
        {
            if (patchRequests == null || !patchRequests.Any())
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Cannot complete operation, collection parameter is null or empty");
            }

            var errors = new List<string>();

            using (var transaction = await _service.BeginTransactionAsync())
            {
                foreach (var patchRequest in patchRequests)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var currentEntity = await _service.GetByIdAsync(patchRequest.Id);

                        if (currentEntity == null)
                        {
                            errors.Add($"Entity with id {patchRequest.Id} not found.");
                            continue;
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            PatchHelper.ApplyPatch(currentEntity, patchRequest.Changes);
                            await _service.UpdateAsync(currentEntity);
                        }
                        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                        {
                            errors.Add($"An error occurred while updating entity with id {patchRequest.Id}: {ex.Message}");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        errors.Add($"An error occurred while retrieving entity with id: {patchRequest.Id}. Exception: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }

                if (errors.Any())
                {
                    await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                    return BadRequest(string.Join("\n", errors));
                }

                await transaction.CommitAsync();
            }

            return Ok("Batch update successful.");
        }
    }
    public class PatchObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> Changes { get; set; }
    }
}

